# optimize triangular join in large data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a large table @tbl, I want to find out co-relation between each cid available in @tbl the formula is provided by client and we have done a sample testing 
for 2-3 cids and values are fine but when we tried to execute this on the whole dataset this is taking more time.

Is there any way to change query because I am using triangular join to find values of each cid to another cid on the basis of currency and mdate.

please suggest.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
    (CID int NOT NULL,
    MDATE date NOT NULL,
    CURRENCY char(3) NOT NULL,
    LOG_VAL  float,
    PRIMARY KEY(CID,CURRENCY,MDATE )
    );



insert into @tbl  
values (19617,'2016-12-07','USD',0.0269613952992653),
(19617,'2016-12-08','USD',-0.0215989790114737),
(19617,'2016-12-09','USD',-0.00354231630415585),
(19617,'2016-12-12','USD',0.0181775886282026), 
(20114,'2016-12-07','USD',0.0126117755008134),
(20114,'2016-12-08','USD',0.000804521846928715),
(20114,'2016-12-09','USD',0.0137173496839721),
(20114,'2016-12-12','USD',0.0227472087663449),
(19458,'2016-12-07','USD',0.0126117755008134),
(19458,'2016-12-08','USD',0.000804521846928715),
(19458,'2016-12-09','USD',0.0137173496839721),
(19458,'2016-12-12','USD',0.0227472087663449) 


SELECT b.CID, C.CID 
   ,(COUNT(*)*SUM(b.LOG_VAL*c.LOG_VAL) - SUM(b.LOG_VAL) * SUM(c.LOG_VAL))
   /    (
   SQRT(COUNT(*) * SUM(b.LOG_VAL*b.LOG_VAL) - SUM(b.LOG_VAL) * SUM(b.LOG_VAL))
   * SQRT(COUNT(*) * SUM(c.LOG_VAL*c.LOG_VAL) - SUM(c.LOG_VAL) * SUM(c.LOG_VAL))
   )AS correl 
FROM  @tbl B     
JOIN  @tbl AS C
ON b.CID <> c.CID 
AND b.CURRENCY = c.CURRENCY
AND b.MDATE = c.MDATE
GROUP BY  b.CID, C.CID
```

Comment: Run your query in SSMS. Make sure you press the `include actual query plan` before you run it. Look at the query plan. If SQL Server suggests adding indexes, add them. rinse and repeat.

Comment: is there any better way to write this query, i do not want to use self join and triangular join. can this be achieve using window function?

Comment: How large is your dataset?  Since this is really only triangular in the set where currency=currency and mdate=mdate, it seems like the join is probably not the problem. If you were to remove the complex math and just select the sum of the log_val columns you would probably find that the performance is reasonable.  I think the multiple sqrt functions on the sums of products is where you are running into performance problems with a large dataset.

Comment: i have tried that but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM  @tbl B JOIN
      @tbl C
      ON b.CID <> c.CID AND
         b.CURRENCY = c.CURRENCY AND
         b.MDATE = c.MDATE
GROUP BY  b.CID, C.CID ;
```

You want an index on `@tbl(currency, mdate, cid, log_val)`.

Indexes on table variables are supported since SQL Server 2014.  Prior to that, you an just use a regular variable.

Comment: i have use @tbl to show data here but actually this table is temp table in code and proper indexes are created. i want any other approach instead of this self join if that can make this query run faster. on a large amount of data self join is not giving me better result.i am looking for alternative like window function or cross apply or anything that would optimize my query. also in execution plan i am not getting any index suggestion.

Comment: @nextaxtion . . . An explanation of what the calculation is trying to do would help.  Given the expression, though, I'm not optimistic that window functions can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can cut it in half with

```
ON b.CID < c.CID
```

Right now you are doing each pair twice

Try index

```
PRIMARY KEY(MDATE, CURRENCY, CID)
```

Is there a reason to not use decimal rather than float?  You should get better performance with decimal.

Consider integer for currency and scale it.

Use a FK with tinyint on currency will help a little.

I don't think there is some magic window function here.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you'll make this performant on a large dataset.  If you are willing to limit the set, eg. by selecting only one currency and a month's frame, you'd need to add an index on currrency and mdate, perhaps even adding cid as third column in that index.

Comment: the issue is still not resolved. I have done all the possible suggestion that are provided.

I am again requesting if anyone can suggest any other approach. I am calculating co-relation between all the cid in this table by using self join and that formula.

Comment: What indexes do you have on your table now?